# Using ExpansionTile on GridView without moving other items

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to, when expading an ExpansionTile in a GridView instead of making the other items of the list to lower to instead expand on top of them?

If not, is there any other Widget I can use?

What am I tryin to achieve is:

A GridView with 4 items per row. Some of those items can be expanded to show more information. Currently If I do so, the grid gets readjusted (so the expanded item opens and around it is empty)
I wanted to expand the item and not move the Grid items at all. (to them perhaps Black out the screen a bit)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `ExpansionTile` with `OverflowBox` and set the `alignment` to `Alignment.topCenter` and as well set the `maxHeight`. Here I set `reverse: true` to the `GridView` so that the `ExpansionTile` on the top will have greater z-axis than the bottom.

```dart
GridView.count(
  // ...
  reverse: true,
  children: [
    for (final number in List.generate(8, (i) => i + 1))
      OverflowBox(
        maxHeight: 1000,
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: ExpansionTile(
          // ...
        ),
      ),
  ],
)
```

[Demonstration video](https://imgur.com/a/1No9DR9)

[Try it in DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c3815752a318903ec0c9a56ff5f6ffab) (make sure to shrink the output screen width so that the expanded tile will overflow through the other tile)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, although now the list got reversed , any other way to achieve the z-axis change without reverting the list (or having to generated the children from last to first)