# Expanding a ExpansionTille with overflow on a GridView

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build an GridView with a list of ExpansionTile (to captalize on the lazy loading).
After some help from here: [Using ExpansionTile on GridView without moving other items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77856470/using-expansiontile-on-gridview-without-moving-other-items/77857446#77857446)

I'm facing some other issues:

- Making the expanded item to be in front (without reverting the list as suggested as in my case the order matters, and reversing make it start from the bottom)
- If I go to the end of the list and expand the last tile, the expanded won't be visible (off screen). Not sure what I can do to fix this
- Currently I'm adding all my text and images in the title property of the ExpanstionTile, otherwise it won't take the full card size. Are there alternatives?

Any help on any of the three issues is greatly appreciated

Here's a screenshot on how it looks right now:
[image]

And here is the code for the page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../components/app_bar.dart';

class TestListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestListScreen({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<TestListScreen> createState() => _TestListScreenState();
}

class _TestListScreenState extends State<TestListScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBarBase(
        title: const Text(
          "Test",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        actions: null,
        color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GridView.count(
                    crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                    crossAxisCount: 6,
                    childAspectRatio: 2,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    children: List.generate(200, (index) {
                      return OverflowBox(
                        maxHeight: 1000,
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Card(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                          child: ExpansionTile(
                            trailing: SizedBox(),
                            title: FittedBox(
                              fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      FittedBox(
                                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "${index} THIS IS THE NAME",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 50),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      FittedBox(
                                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                        child: Text(
                                          "THIS IS THE OTHER NAME",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 25,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Colors.white),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 50,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 50,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                            collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.black26,
                            children: const [
                              Text('This is tile '),
                              ListTile(title: Text('This is tile ')),
                              ListTile(title: Text('This is tile ')),
                              ListTile(title: Text('This is tile ')),
                              ListTile(title: Text('This is tile ')),
                              ListTile(title: Text('This is tile ')),
                              ListTile(title: Text('This is tile ')),
                              ListTile(title: Text('This is tile ')),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2. for the second issue, try to increase the page height. or add more padding of the parent widgets.
3. Try to replace grid with this:

   child: GridView.builder(
   gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
   maxCrossAxisExtent: 200, // Adjust this based on your needs
   crossAxisSpacing: 5,
   mainAxisSpacing: 5,
   childAspectRatio: 2,
   ),)